# Identify mostly visited places when coordinates (latitude and longitude) are given

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-analysis

I'm working on a project where the locations visited by people are captured in terms of latitude and longitude and analyze all these coordinates to identify the mostly visited places.

I finished up to retrieving the all the coordinates visited by the people and sending those data to a database as well as writing them to a text file. I tried to cluster the data by retrieving them from the text files. Since I'm totally new to machine learning, I'm finding it hard to figure out what to do exactly with the data.

So can anyone please help me to figure out a correct approach to identify the mostly visited places by analyzing the coordinates that I'm having ?

Comment: Couldn't you just sort the data and find the largest?

Comment: This seems like a trivial task.  Are there any details you are not telling us?

Comment: Mark : The data sets will be large ones. So i doubt sorting data is the most efficient way of doing this

Comment: PM 77-1 : Well, basically this is the task what I need to achieve. Can you please tell me what kind of other details you need to know ?

Comment: We don't have your data, and your question is too vague on what you have and what you want... I don't think we will be able to help much unless you add much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, there is quite a bit of missing information for this question but I will have a go from what I understand.

I can think of two scenarios, and the approach to solving each is not something I would really consider as machine learning. The first scenario is that you have already attributed the lat/long to a definitive location e.g. “visitors of Buckingham Palace”, which would have a set lat/long coordinate associated with it. You’d then be able to generate a list of (Monument_lat, Monument_lon, weight) where weight is the number of visitors attributed to that location. Then it would simply be a case of sorting that list by weight, as has been suggested. I’m not clear on why you don’t think this is the most efficient way (list sorting is trivial and fast).

The other scenario involves raw lat/long data from a phone where you might have extremely similar lat/long pairs, but not exactly the same. You want to group these to single locations. You could divide the region of interest into small rectangular zones where you store the lat/long data for each of the corners of the zones. You then run a ray-casting algorithm to solve the point-in-polygon [problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Ray_casting_algorithm), thereby attributing the raw lat/long data to a zone, and you find the centre coordinate of each zone to apply the "weight".

I don’t know what language you are using, but there is an open-source ray casting algorithm for Python. Depending on the scope of your problem, there could be slight alterations that you might want to make. Firstly, if you are defining the location by a monument name and you don’t have too many, you could go on Google Maps and define your own lat/long corners of zones, to store as a list. If you’re not interested in classifying in a monument-name fashion, you simply divide the whole area into even rectangles. If you wanted, say, 10 metre precision across an entire country then you need to have layers of different sized zones to minimise the computational effort. You might divide the country into 10x10km squares and do a ray cast on that scale to give a rough sorting stage, before doing another ray cast on a 10x10m scale within the 10x10km zone.